# XGboost: what is the sense of plotting trees when there are over hundred

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

There are method in xgboost:

```
xgb.plot_tree(model, num_trees=2)
```

if the argument n_estimators are over more than 10 or 100,
what is the sense of plotting one of them?

Comment: That's a very open question Jimmy. Why won't you tell us what you want to "get" from plotting the trees ?

Comment: @EranMoshe For example, interpreting predictors by the splitting value. I cannot come up with a senario that interpreting the data by visuzlizing the some of the thound tree makes any sense. It only tells the idea of the booting tree, but not providing insights for the applied data from my point of view.

Comment: I've answered to someone asked something similar. I used a package called SHAP. and use its shap values to visualize results. here's the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51965203/visualize-strengths-and-weaknesses-of-a-sample-from-pre-trained-model/51981082#51981082

Comment: @EranMoshe thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xgb.plot_tree()` plots only a single tree from the n number of trees created.
e.g. `xgb.plot_tree(model, num_trees=2)` will plot the tree at index 2.

Check out an example [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/visualize-gradient-boosting-decision-trees-xgboost-python/)

Comment: yes, I know that. My point is what is the sense of visualize that? if there are many of them

Answer (score -1):

If you're interested in looking at you're predictions at a very granular level (e.g. for specific individuals or whatever it is you're predicting on). It can be useful to find the trees that contribute most to the overall model score and then plot these. I've found this process quite useful in the past.